# Is it necessarily true that $x$ is forced to be nonnegative in the case of $\sqrt{x^3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, examples-counterexamples, radicals

I'm reading a textbook on Precalculus, and it makes the following claim:

> If you have a single odd power under the square root, like $\sqrt{x^3}$, the variable is forced to be nonnegative, so absolute value is not necessary.

I'm familiar with the property that for any $a\in\mathbb R$, $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$, but I don't see how it can even be used here to demonstrate $x$ is forced to be $\ge 0$. Can someone please explain what they're trying to demonstrate with this statement? I don't understand, because if $x=-1$, then $$\sqrt{(-1)^3} = \sqrt{-1} = i.$$

It just leaves me with a big fat "WHY?!" seeing that claim and coming up with this counterexample, but maybe I just don't understand what they're trying to claim. I see no other assumptions stated in the chapter prior to that, so I'm not sure what is even happening.

Comment: The statement is simply false.

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html i hope this will help you

Comment: I would presume the book works in the context of real numbers only. And so $\sqrt{x^3}$ would only be defined when $x\geq0$. This is in contrast with $\sqrt{x^2}$, which would still be defined for all $x$.

Comment: `absolute value is not necessary` "*Is not necessary*" where, and in order for what to happen? Some more context would help. If, at that point, $\,\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}\,$ is considered to be the *real* square root, then for $\,\sqrt{x^3}\,$ to be defined it is required that $x^3 \ge 0 \iff x \ge 0\,$.

Comment: What book are you reading? (I'm curious whether it's a poorly-written sentence or an actual (huge) error.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, It's Cynthia Young's Precalculus, 2nd Ed. It's a textbook for undergrads. I've been thrown the job of teaching this course, and it just made a claim I found somewhat outrageous claim. At this point in the text, we are not working with complex numbers but it mentions how to determine whether the answer is real or nonreal.

Comment: Generally speaking, the wonderful rules on exponents that we learned in school are valid only for nonnegative real inputs; and the outputs will also be nonnegative.

Answer (score 4):

Because the *real* function $\sqrt{x}$ is generally understood as a function from $[0,+\infty)$ to $[0,+\infty)$. Hence, if $x<0$, as is $x=t^3$ for any $t<0$, then $\sqrt{x}$ is undefined.

In the context of *complex* analysis, this is much more nuanced. Any nonzero complex number has $n$ distinct $n$-th roots, so that in particular $x^{1/2}$ $\,''$$=$$''\,$$\sqrt{x}$ is now no longer singled-valued.

Taking your example, we can see that both $i^2=(-i)^2=-1$, so why would you prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

We want to treat $\sqrt{x^3}$ as a function

\begin{align}
   f:(D \subseteq \mathbb R) &\to \mathbb R \\
   x &\to f(x)=\sqrt{x^3}
\end{align}

and we ask what is the largest possible set that $D$ could be equal to?

If $x < 0$, then $x^3<0$ and $\sqrt{x^3}$ does not exists, or, at least, is not a real number. So we end up with

\begin{align}
   f:[0, \infty) &\to \mathbb R \\
   x &\to \sqrt{x^3}
\end{align}

Assuming that $x \ge 0$, we can simplify this to $\sqrt{x^3} = x\sqrt{x}$.

If we are talking about the function

\begin{align}
   g:(D \subseteq \mathbb R) &\to \mathbb R \\
   x &\to g(x)=\sqrt{x^2}
\end{align}

then, for all $x$, $x^2 \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{x^2}$ will always be a real number. So we end up with
\begin{align}
   g:\mathbb R &\to \mathbb R \\
   x &\to \sqrt{x^2}
\end{align}

It turns out that this is true: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.